# how to get node name in Oracle SQL extract() with xPath (10g)

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath, xmltype, nodename

Here is a XML file:

```
<ROOT>
<A>
    <B>2</B>
    <C>3</C>
    <D>4</D>
</A> 
</ROOT>
```

How to get the **tag** name "C" through xPath. The function name() does not work here in extract.

It reports Errors:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00601: Invalid token
```

`gXmlDOM` is the xml string above, how to do this in SQL?

```
select XMLType(gXmlDOM).extract(p_xmlPath).getStringVal() from dual;
```

Comment: What's the contents of the `p_xmlPath` column?

Comment: That's the xpath string like "/ROOT/A"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for...

```
Select xmltype('<ROOT><A><B>2</B><C>3</C><D>4</D></A></ROOT>')
       .extract('ROOT/A/*[2]')
       .getrootelement()
  From dual;
```